# models in Django issue with foreign key

Tags: python, django

I have project on Django and me need to create the model which will be foreign key from other if some value is true.

I'll try to explain.
I have some model :

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
    boolean = models.BooleanField(default=1
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

class SomeClass2(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
    child_item = models.ForeignKey(SomeClass, to_field='name')
```

What I must do then child_item get name only if boolean is True.

Comment: What are you asking? Please illustrate your needs with an example. Any reason for setting `to_field='name'`?

Comment: For example on admin created item "SomeClass" : name - test1; bollean = true and name - test2; bollean = false.
And in "SomeClass2" i must see only the first item "test1" and that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit foreign key choices with [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class SomeClass(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    boolean = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)

class SomeClass2(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)

    child_item = models.ForeignKey(SomeClass, to_field='name',
                                   limit_choices_to={'boolean': True})
```